# What is the difference between Password and Keychain?

Tags: macos, ios, password, keychain

What is the main difference between Password under settings and Keychain? I noticed that upon adding new credentials in Keychain, it is not included in the Passwords. However adding credentials in Passwords will be included in Keychain. It seems better to add credentials in Passwords since it will be sync across your Apple devices.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between Password and Keychain?

Passwords is a subset of Keychain.  You can think of Passwords as a rudimentary password manager to handle your username and password/passkey are securely stored.

Keychain, on the other hand, is a full-fledged secure compartment for items like usernames, passwords, certificates, credit cards, etc.  A "key" stored in the chain can be a username and password, but an entry in Passwords cannot. This is why the data sharing is one directional

Additional reading:

- [Set up iCloud Keychain](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085)
- [How to find saved passwords and passkeys on your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211146)