Newspaper online account password is remembered on my Mac, but doesn't show in Keychain
MacBook Air mid-2013, macOS Big Sur 11.7.10, Safari 16.6.1
I have an online subscription to the San Francisco Chronicle newspaper. When I navigate to the newspaper's website (https://www.sfchronicle.com), the site logs me in and provides access to the online paper. I assume this indicates that the password has been saved in Keychain.
Keychain Access does not, however, show the Chronicle account. When I search Keychain Access for the account itself or for the password (I wrote the password down when I opened the account), neither appears.
Why doesn't the account or password appear in Keychain Access? Is it stored somewhere else? Should I do anything about it?

This might explain why https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/463842/what-is-the-difference-between-password-and-keychain

@KasperJensen Thanks for your comment, but I don't see the relevance of the cited question. The SFChronicle password doesn't appear in Keychain on my Mac, and also doesn't appear in "Passwords" when viewed in iOS. Also my iPhone SE's Settings Menu looks nothing like the screenshot in the cited question, which appears (viz. its use of "Password" rather than the current iOS use of "Passcode"); perhaps an earlier version of iOS behaved differently. In any event, the password I'm looking for is in neither place.

In testing this, are you taking action to log out of the site? Are you quitting the browser (not just closing its window)?

@8None1 You're right, I wasn't signing out. I just tried it, and signed out from the session, and Keychain now shows the saved password. Turn it into an Answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

I suspect you are not fully signing out. Many web applications will set a session cookie which will record the "state" that you are logged in. Session cookies will persist for as long as the browser application is running. Not tabs open, not windows open, but full quit of the application. If the site has an actually "log me out" function, that should clear this session state as well.
If you sign out (or quit the browser) and try logging back in, you should either see saved credentials or be required to enter them and have the opportunity to save them.
